# Find out the Machine Type using its IP address or Name

Tags: windows, operating-system

Is there any way to find out, if a machine is Linux server or Windows Server using its IP Address or Name. No other information is here.

Thanks

Comment: If you can ping the address, a TTL response of approximately 128 probably indicates a Windows server, and a TTL response of approximately 64 probably indicates a UNIX (Linux, Mac OS X, OpenBSD, whatever) server.

Comment: Today I noticed the same thing, but I am not sure it will applicable in all the case especially when the windows server is so slow.

Comment: TTL has nothing to do with the speed or timing of the response.  It limits the number of routers the packet can cross before being discarded, I think in order to prevent a packet from running in circles indefinitely.